# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: link is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. in Next js

Tags: hyperlink, runtime, unhandled, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

import Image from 'next/image'
import MaxWidthWrrapper from './(component)/max_width_wrraper'
import {Button, buttonVariants } from '@/components/ui/button'
import Link from 'next/link'
export default function Home() {
return (
<>


< h1 className='text-4xl font-bold tracking-tighter text-gray-900 sm:txl-6xl '>Your Market For Higher Quality 
  {'       '}

digital assert
 .
   Welcome to DigitalHippo. Every asset on our
platform is verified by our team to ensure our
highest quality standards.

Brower Trending




</>
)
}

i am using this code

i try link one page to an other using button